# Herdar texto do elemento

Tags: html, css

Sem utilizar JS
Preciso de um simples exemplo de como utilizar variaveis nos elementos HTML5 para apresentar seu conteudo.

Na ação hover, o elemento apontado deve ser destacado e passar o texto para elemento com propriedade "herda"

```
<p id="herda">Esta frase muda de acordo com apontar o mouse em cada Item</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item1 Frase 1</li>
    <li>Item2 Outra frase</li>
    <li>Item3 Frase fim</li>
</ul>
```

Suplico por auxilio, pois tá dificil

Comment: Sem JS não existe solução atualmente com CSS para alterar um elemento anterior.

Answer (score 2):

A única diferença é que coloquei o `label` depois dos `li` porque não tem como utilizar um seletor para elementos anteriores, mas da pra jogar para cima facilmente com CSS.

**Importante:** Os elementos devem estar todos no mesmo nível hierárquico.

```css
.texto1:hover ~ #label-modificado:after {
    content: 'Item1 Frase 1';
}
.texto2:hover ~ #label-modificado:after {
    content: 'Item2 Outra frase';
}
.texto3:hover ~ #label-modificado:after {
    content: 'Item3 Frase fim'
}
#label-modificado:after {
    content: 'Esta frase muda de acordo com apontar o mouse em cada Item'
}
```

```html
<li class="texto1">Item1 Frase 1</li>
<li class="texto2">Item2 Outra frase</li>
<li class="texto3">Item3 Frase fim</li>

<label id="label-modificado"></label>
```

`~` é um seletor irmão, ele vai buscar todos elementos posteriores.

`+` que também é um seletor irmão, busca apenas o primeiro posterior.

Mais informações [aqui](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/guia-completo-seletores-css3.php).

Comment: Grato, isto mesmo que desejava... não conhecia simbolo ~ - qual nome do recurso? Mas o problema, agora que TAG "ul" desabilita o efeito, mas preciso mante-la. Onde erro,seria o nível hierárquico.? http://jsfiddle.net/8to46sbk/

Comment: Exatamente, se você remover o `ul` ele funciona porque vai estar no mesmo nível hierárquico

Comment: Mas aí o HTML fica inválido, não? De qualquer maneira a solução é boa, tem como contornar isso - por exemplo colocando o label dentro de um `<li>` e mexer no estilo desse item. Aí o `<ul>` não causa problemas.

Comment: Adicionei algumas informações sobre os seletores na resposta, se quiser dar uma olhada melhor.

Comment: @dandrade Como vai ficar seu HTML final?